# Angular eslint, some rules in html doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, eslint

In an Angular 2+ project, trying to set up some rules in .eslintrc file, the rule `"no-multiple-empty-lines"` is working, but the rule `"quotes"` is ignored by eslint. For example, I would expect the linter to flag `<input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatePicker3">`. Is there something I'm missing?

```js
{
  "files": [
    "*.html"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "quotes": ["error", "single"],
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": ["error", {
      "max": 1,
      "maxEOF": 0 
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: What's a minimal example from a template that _should_ be flagged but isn't?

Comment: @stealththeninja for example: <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatePicker3"> must be flaged

Answer (score 0):

Double-quotes are sometimes required for valid HTML syntax, as compared to JavaScript or Typescript where string assignments can use single, double, or template literals.

Given that, I would think Angular ESLint might handle rules like `quotes` differently in templates. It looks like a [breaking change in 2.0.0](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/ff9c1bcec7cf940adffa051ca58eda5ba6cd7978/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-5) made this adjustment, especially from how I interpret the [updated test snapshot](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/pull/328/files#diff-87dac3b5f23990d72a8c3ee6087f1c3505c330e69aa59da8e8efa021a8db5c7c).